# angles in rhombus when an equilateral triangle is inscribed in it

Tags: geometry, triangles, quadrilateral, angle

When one inscribs an equilateral triangle in a rhombus, all the corners are multiples of 30 degrees. I can see this, but I can't proof it.

Question: How can I proof that the angle ADC is 120 degrees?
[image: equilateral triangle in a rhombus]

**And** how do I claim that the triangle SHB (S being the intersection of the diagonals) is similar with triangle FHC? I can see it and I think there is an easy way with parallel lines (why is EF || AC) and bisectors (the diagonals of a rhombus) but I just can not put my finger on it...

Any help and/or hints are really appreciated.

Comment: This isn't true. You can inscribe an equilateral triangle in a square, which clearly doesn't have any $120^\circ$ angle.

Comment: Perhaps there are some assumptions in the problem setup that you have unintentionally omitted?  A rhombus can be of varied aspects, not just the back-to-back equilateral triangles you seem to illustrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The angle aren't multiples of 30 degree. It can be any value you like. If $D$ is moved upwards  then $A$ and $C$ contract inwards (and move upwards as well) and vice versa.

Some examples:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect. Rhombuses of varying aspect ratio are possible to be circumscribed through $DAC$ with a variable height $BD$.